# Nginx Regex example to get a value between two commas

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Suppose I am hitting the URL

http://www.example.com?state=env,test,appname,maha,observation_code,123456

and in $args_state I am getting this string

state=env,test,appname,maha,observation_code,123456

I want value between first and second comma
In this example if we perform regex then it should return test. based on that value I want to redirect url to somewhere else.
I am making some changes in nginx.conf file.

Comment: What have you done so far? Which programing language?

Comment: You could split on the `=`, the comma and then count...

Answer (score 1):

Unless other conditions are needed, simple string functions will more than suffice:

```
t = """state=env,test,appname,maha,observation_code,123456""".split("=")[1].split(',')[1]
print(t)
# test
```